# Is it possible for a C++ iterator to have gaps and not be linear?

Tags: c++, iterator

I wrote a C++ iterator to go over an `std::string` which is UTF-8.

The idea is for the iterator to return `char32_t` characters instead of bytes. The iterator can be used to go forward or backward. I can also rewind and I suppose the equivalent of `rbegin()`.

Since a character can span multiple bytes, my position within the `std::string` may *jump* by 2, 3, or 4 bytes (the library throws if an invalid character is encountered).

This also mean the distance to a certain character does not always increment one by one. In other words, `++it` may increment the position by a number from 1 to 4 and `--it` reverse subtract in a similar manner.

Is that an expected/legal behavior for a C++ iterator?

Comment: As you described it, as long as the "position" is not accessable (is private), there are no "gaps" or "nonlinearity" so there's clearly no issue with this as a BidirectionalIterator.  It probably can't be a RandomAccessIterator, however.

Comment: Also, maybe take a look at how QString from Qt handles UTF characters for another example. With QString, the character data is encapulated with another class in the accessor functions instead of providing direct access to the underlying data.

Comment: @Remarkod A QString handles UTF-16 and _they don't properly handle surrogates_ (i.e. they return `unsigned short` for the characters). Maybe Qt v6 will enhance that part, though. So in effect they can manage an array of `unsigned short`.

Comment: For the user of the iterator, incrementing just means position so that dereferencing the iterator gets the next value from the container.   What happens internally - including jumping by varying distances over elements of an underlying container, doesn't matter to the caller.     The job of the iterator and its operations (e.g. `operator++()`) is to keep things consistent for the caller even if, internally, those operations shift by arbitrary amounts.    You'll be in trouble if the caller can directly manipulate the internal state of the iterator though and doesn't ensure consistency.

Comment: A bidirectional iterator does just this.  Think of `std::map`, it is an RB Tree, so iteration could skip whole branches.

Comment: Yes, that's **exactly** what iterators are for: to provide a uniform to a possibly non-uniform data structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many algorithms in C++ work equally well with plain pointers in addition to iterators. `std::copy` will work with plain pointers, just fine. `std::find_if` will be happy too. And so on.

By a fortunate coincidence `std::copy` invokes the `++` operator on the pointers you feed to it. Well, guess what? Passing a bunch `int *`s to `std::copy` results in the actual pointer being increment by `sizeof(int)`, instead of 1.

`std::copy` won't care.

The properties of iterators and their requirements are defined in terms of ***the logical results*** and ***the logical effects*** of what the various operators cause to happen (as well as which operators are valid for a given iterator). Whether the internal implementation of an iterator increments the internal value, that represents the iterator in some way, by 1, 2, 4, or 42, is immaterial. Note that reverse iterators result in the actual internal pointer getting ***decremented*** by its `++` operator overload.

If your custom iterator's implementation of the `++`, `--`, `*`, `[]`, `+`, and `-` operators (whichever ones are appropriate for your iterator) meets all requirements of their assigned iterator category, then the actual effects of these operators on the actual raw pointer value, that represents your iterator, is irrelevant.

The answer to your question is as follows, assuming that your custom iterator is a random access iterator: if all the required operator overloads meet all requirements of a random access iterator, then the actual effects on the underlying pointer value are irrelevant.

The same holds true for any iterator category, not just random access.

Comment: At this point, I did not implement the `[]` operator, since it's just bidirectional, not random. It would be possible to implement the `[]` but that would be costly (you have to parse the whole string from the start to find the position).

Comment: Implemeniting a legacyrandomaccess iterator isn't possible the way the OP describes.  The issues are not trivial, and this answer does not address them.